# CygWin Configure script finds wrong Python version

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, cygwin, autoconf

I am trying to compile a library (libWally) on Windows 10, using the latest versions from CygWin.  (Automake 11-1, Autoconf 13-1).  Running the command ./configure gives me the error below.  My Python version is 3.8.5, well above the 2.1.0 minimum the script says it requires.  Not sure if configure is finding the wrong version or has some other error, and am not skilled enough at reading the configure.log file to determine what is happening.

```
This version of the AC_PYTHON_DEVEL macro
doesn't work properly with versions of Python before
2.1.0. You may need to re-run configure, setting the
variables PYTHON_CPPFLAGS, PYTHON_LIBS, PYTHON_SITE_PKG,
PYTHON_EXTRA_LIBS and PYTHON_EXTRA_LDFLAGS by hand.
Moreover, to disable this check, set PYTHON_NOVERSIONCHECK
to something else than an empty string.
```

EDIT: In bash, I set the environment variable PYTHON_VERSION to "3.8.5", and reran.  The version check error disappears, but then tells me it can't find "Python3.8.5" in the system path.  Since Python on my machine is installed in a "./Python38" directory, I change the variable to "38", but it still tells me it can't find Python38 in the system path. However, it is there.'   The relevant portion of the configuration file appears to be this:

```
set dummy python$PYTHON_VERSION; ac_word=$2
{ $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: checking for $ac_word" >&5
$as_echo_n "checking for $ac_word... " >&6; }
if ${ac_cv_path_PYTHON+:} false; then :
  $as_echo_n "(cached) " >&6
else
  case $PYTHON in
  [\\/]* | ?:[\\/]*)
  ac_cv_path_PYTHON="$PYTHON" # Let the user override the test with a path.
  ;;
  *)
  as_save_IFS=$IFS; IFS=$PATH_SEPARATOR
for as_dir in $PATH
do
  IFS=$as_save_IFS
  test -z "$as_dir" && as_dir=.
    for ac_exec_ext in '' $ac_executable_extensions; do
  if as_fn_executable_p "$as_dir/$ac_word$ac_exec_ext"; then
    ac_cv_path_PYTHON="$as_dir/$ac_word$ac_exec_ext"
    $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: found $as_dir/$ac_word$ac_exec_ext" >&5
    break 2
  fi
done
  done
IFS=$as_save_IFS

  ;;
esac
fi
PYTHON=$ac_cv_path_PYTHON
if test -n "$PYTHON"; then
  { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: $PYTHON" >&5
$as_echo "$PYTHON" >&6; }
else
  { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: no" >&5
$as_echo "no" >&6; }
fi


    if test -z "$PYTHON"; then
       as_fn_error $? "Cannot find python$PYTHON_VERSION in your system path" "$LINENO" 5
```

EDIT AGAIN: Setting the PYTHON var in bash to the path to Python solved the path error, but cause the original version error to reappear.  I am including that configuration section:

```
    if test -n ">= '2.7.0'"; then
        { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: checking for a version of Python >= '2.7.0'" >&5
$as_echo_n "checking for a version of Python >= '2.7.0'... " >&6; }
        ac_supports_python_ver=`$PYTHON -c "import sys; \
            ver = sys.version.split ()[0]; \
            print (ver >= '2.7.0')"`
        if test "$ac_supports_python_ver" = "True"; then
           { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: yes" >&5
$as_echo "yes" >&6; }
        else
            { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: no" >&5
$as_echo "no" >&6; }
            as_fn_error $? "this package requires Python >= '2.7.0'.
If you have it installed, but it isn't the default Python
interpreter in your system path, please pass the PYTHON_VERSION
variable to configure. '''
```

Comment: Without knowing anything more that what you've written here, maybe the scripting requires a version of Python 2.  Recall that Python 2 and Python 3 are very different and most Python scripts written for Python 2 will not work (without modifications) in Python 3.  So perhaps this scripting is looking for Python 2 and just printing a confusing message when it finds Python 3.  However, you haven't provided enough information here for anyone to really know for sure what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I posted a section from the configuration file that may be relevant.  What else can you suggest I provide to give people more information?

Comment: Please be very careful with your cases.  POSIX systems are case-sensitive, and so `Python38` is not the same thing as `python38`.  You have both tags `linux` and `cygwin` which is confusing.  You say "Python38 appears on the system path" but then you say "installed in a ./Python38 directory".  In all, your description is a bit haphazard and you don't show us your actual PATH value, the fully qualified location of Python, etc.

Comment: From the above section of configure script it looks to me like you can just set `PYTHON=/path/to/python` and it will just use that python interpreter: have you tried that?

Comment: This is the first gcc project I have tried to compile, so please excuse if I'm not conveying the information properly.  My Windows path to Python looks like 'c:\users\myusername\Appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python38', but in bash echoing the path command shows it in the form, '/cygdrive/c/Users/myusername/...etc'   I assume I should set the PYTHON variable in the script to what appears in Bash?

Comment: Putting the bash path into the PYTHON variable got past the path error, but it also caused the version error (version must be > 2.7.0)  to reappear.  This is the start of the config section; I can't understand what text string "test" is testing against: `code`  if test -n ">= '2.7.0'"; then...

Comment: Mixing Cygwin tools ( automake, automake..) with a Windows Python is a recipe for problems as they manage differently line termination and other stuff (CRLF vs LF ..)

Answer (score 0):

When you say "reappear" I don't know what you mean since the message you mention in your comment doesn't appear to match any previous error message from your question.  Really, it's best if you include the error in your question as a cut and paste exactly from your terminal rather than paraphrasing in comments.

In any event, the `test -n ">= 2.7.0"` is irrelevant.  That's always true so it will always try to run the `$PYTHON` command.  The question is why that fails.

If you run this at your shell prompt, what does it print:

```
$PYTHON -c "import sys; ver = sys.version.split()[0]; print (ver >= '2.7.0')"
```

?  If it prints `True` then I suspect the info provided by @matzeri is the issue: the output ends in a CRLF because it's a Windows tool, while POSIX tools expect line endings to be just LF.  That means that the value generated is really `True<CR>` which is not equal to `True`, so the comparison of `$ac_supports_python_ver` fails.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help!  MadSci, your script line does print true, so I assume it's a problem with using the Windows version of Python.  I will install the Cygwin version of Python and proceed from there.